# Añadir prefijos a clases e ids de CSS en PHP

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

Tengo un módulo en [php](/questions/tagged/php) que se encarga de buscar todos los archivos css de una carpeta, "*minificarlos*" y escribir todo el contenido en un nuevo css.

```
private function cssFile($css_file, $widget_id = '') {
    $css = '';
    $css .= file_get_contents($css_file);
    $css = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $css);
    $css = str_replace(': ', ':', $css);
    $css = str_replace(array("\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $css);
    return $css;
}
```

¿De qué manera puedo agregar un prefijo a cada uno de las clases e Ids?

No puedo hacer un [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php) porque me afectaría los colores: `rgba(0,0,0,0.5), #fff;`

Comment: Normalmente después de cada clase o id tendrías una coma (,) o una llave ({), tal vez por ese lado puedas encontrar la regex que necesites.

Comment: Jeje, ya estoy en ello. Con una regex creo que es imposible o no llego a tanto pero con 2 igual se puede. Si me sale todo bien publico la respuesta enseguida. Gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Podrías agregar algunos de ejemplos que dices que no has podidos modificar con expresiones regulares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías buscar todos los `#` y `.` que estén seguidos por `{` sin tener ninguna `}` en el medio.

### RegEx

```regex
/[#.]\K(?=[a-z0-9][^{}]*+{)/i
```

### Descripción

- `[#.]` - Coincide con 1 caracter que sea `#` o `.`
- `\K` - Resetea la coincidencia (para que el `#` o `.` no se incluya en el reemplazo)
- `(?=[a-z0-9][^{}]*+{)` Lookahead (tiene que coincidir, pero no consume caracteres) para:

  - `[a-z0-9]` - El nombre de la clase o id debería empezar con una letra o número
  - `[^{}]*+` - seguido de cualquier caracter que no sea `{` ni `}`
  - `{` - y luego el `{` que abre el estilo.
- `/i` - Para que coincida con mayúsculas y minúsculas.

### Código

```php
function prefijarClasesYIds($css_file, $prefijo = '') {
    return preg_replace( '/[#.]\K(?=[a-z0-9][^{}]*+{)/i', $prefijo, $css_file);
}
```

### Ejemplo

```php
$css_file = "
                a:hover, a:visited, a.unId {
                    prop: #aaa;
                }

                body, #fff, a:link {
                    prop: #bbb;
                }

                .algun_id, #clase1, #clase2.otroId {
                    prop: #ddd;
                }
            ";

$ejPrefijo = "PREFIJO";
$css_file = prefijarClasesYIds( $css_file, $ejPrefijo);

echo $css_file;
```

#### Resultado

```
a:hover, a:visited, a.PREFIJOunId {
    prop: #aaa;
}

body, #PREFIJOfff, a:link {
    prop: #bbb;
}

.PREFIJOalgun_id, #PREFIJOclase1, #PREFIJOclase2.PREFIJOotroId {
    prop: #ddd;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo en Ideone](http://ideone.com/T2xHex)</kbd>

---

**Nota:** Se asume que ya eliminaste los comentarios antes de esta función. Y quizás podría fallar con algún ejemplo raro, pero en ese caso, agregá ese ejemplo en la pregunta y lo adapto.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Funciona muy bien tu Regex!

Answer (score 1):

A través de Regex me resultó imposible dado que hay valores dentro del css que no se pueden diferenciar con un solo patron, ejemplo **#Id**, **#comentario**, **#fff**.
Aunque no estoy orgulloso de mi código basado en **str_replace** es lo único que me funciona correctamente.

Lo comparto por si a alguien le resulta útil:

```
private function cssFile($css_file, $id = '') {
    $css = '';
    $css .= file_get_contents($css_file);
    $css = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $css);
    $css = str_replace(
        array(": ", "\n", "\t", ", ", "    ", "}#", " {", "}.", ",.", " > "),
        array(':', "","", ",", "", "}#".$id."#", "{", "}#".$id.".", ",#".$id.".", ">")
    , $css);
```